# Instagram API OauthException: "You must provide a client_id"

Tags: python, api, instagram, python-requests, access-token

When I'm trying to receive an access_token from `Instagram.` I do the following request

```
params = {
    'client_id' : config.INSTAGRAM_APP_ID,
    'client_secret' : config.INSTAGRAM_APP_SECRET_KEY,
    'grant_type' : 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' : '`my localhost`',
    'code' : code
    }
r = requests.post('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', params = params)
```

And receive error:

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "You must provide a client_id"}
```

What can I do with these?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Has anyone solved this please

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this by putting these params in the (x-www-form-encoded) **body** instead of in the **header** (credit to https://github.com/request/request/issues/983#issuecomment-57005849 for the idea).

NB: I am not using the python wrapper.

Comment: Correct! With x-www-form-urlencoded the request works also with Postman

Answer (score 0):

Use `app_id`, and `app_secret`.

For postman, put the body params in `x-www-form-urlencoded`.